# awk: detect content separated by arbitrary character instead of spaces?

Tags: awk

Is there a way to make awk detect content separated by commas (or any other character) instead of spaces?

e.g. a file (.csv) contains a list of contacts in the format "title","first-name","last-name","e-mail". How would you use awk to print all the first names?

Comment: `awk -F, '{print $2}'` -F specifies field separator and 2nd field is where first name is stored

Comment: @MelBurslan Thank you. A small additional question: the tutorial I'm working through puts the single quote marks inside the brackets: `awk {'print $2'}`. Is one (i.e. inside or outside) better than the other / preferred?

Comment: makes no difference which one comes first. It is a programming style. From my personal experience, `awk -F, '{ awk commands here }`' is the preferred usage, but at the end it doesn't matter if `'` or `{` comes first. It even works with wrong order of signs, such as `awk -F, '{print $2'} filename`.. notice the open and close sequence of signs. But it is a very sloppy programming exercise and should not be encouraged, in my opinion

Comment: @MelBurslan Thank you - that's very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the *field separator*, either as a command line option

```
awk -F, '{print $2}' file.csv
```

or using the built-in `FS` variable

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=","} {print $2}' file.csv
```